# Remove widget from React APP

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, mern

Im starting to learn React and I use the following repo:

https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter

as a starter for creating full-stack react application , the problem is that when you run this project out of the box you get some widget which looks like following
[image]

I try many things to in order to remove it, what is it this widget how can I disable it?

I try to remove it from the postReducer and nothing happen...
how to search for it and disable it ?

Comment: That is the redux dev tools, you should see it near the entry point for the client app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at this line of code:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.isMounted && !window.devToolsExtension && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && <DevTools />}
        <div>
          <Helmet...
```

https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter/blob/master/client/modules/App/App.js#L34

you'll see the `devToolsExtension` being added if `NODE_ENV` is `development`.

You can remove that line if you do not want the dev tools to show up.

Comment: Thanks Davin ! I'll mark as answer in few min when I can :) , btw did you use this repo ?

Comment: Can I ask you someting in general since I Need to create some basic full stack app ...

Comment: Sure. What's up? Was on the move earlier.

Comment: Happy new year :) , I want to create some simple blog app just for demo, the mern repo is ok (exactly what I need for starting create post and see the previos posts )  besides the code is very hard to understand , do you know about other project which i can use for this case which is easy to understand and modify? I know that it can be subjective but i''ll happy to hear if you know of course about other options. thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of a react blog example, but I'm sure if you search around you can find one. Building your own can be a good way to learn. Good luck and happy new year!